# build pcl 1.7.2 and vtk 6.3 with qt 5.5 in VS2013 64bit

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5, vtk, point-cloud-library

How to build with CMake pcl 1.7.2 and vtk 6.3 with qt 5.5, boost 1.59 and all other dependencies in VS2013 64bit?
pcl web is out of date with both information and precompiled versions.
CMake variables do not coincide with those in tutorials and building flann from source gives me an error.

Comment: to improve you question add the error and Please read How to ask stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Manual to build those from source:

http://tech-filip-sladek.blogspot.sk/2015/11/cmake-compile-pcl-172-vtk-63-qt-55-in.html

Download prebuilt(you must have already installed qt5.5):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9NzHDWA7ywCWjZ0Vy04Tkk5Smc/view?usp=sharing